# Get top items number from wordpress menu

Tags: menus, walker

I've made a menu in WordPress backend with 3 levels depth. 
(four main tabs with two sub level items)

I would like to know how I can get the number of tabs created automatically and add this number to a class on the `ul` (i.e: `.item-4`)

Any ideas? I'm already using a [custom walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`wp_get_nav_menu_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object) to retrieve the menu as an object, which you can subsequently establish the length of. Like this:

```
$wpse140949_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'your-menu-name-or-slug' );
$tabcount = $wpse140949_menu->count;
```

You can the use this on your call to `wp_nav_menu`:

```
wp_nav_menu ( array (
  'menu_class' => 'item-' . $tabcount,
  ....
  ));
```